# how to jump to the newly created buffer/window automatically in Emacs

Tags: emacs

In compilation, occur search, grep search, etc., Emacs will create a new buffer in a separate window to show the results, is there anyway to jump to that window automatically? It is useful because then I can use `n` and `p` instead of `M-g n` and `M-g p` to move to next and previous items; plus, the buffer can be quit quickly with `q`. Currently I manually switch to the new buffer every time I run those commands, which is just annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use advice.

For example to jump to the grep buffer use the following advice:

```
(defadvice compilation-start (after compilation-start-maximize activate)
  (when (equal mode 'grep-mode)
    (switch-to-buffer "*grep*")
    ;; you may want to maximize the buffer
    (delete-other-windows)))
```

For occur you can use the following advice

```
(defadvice occur-1 (after occur-maximize activate)
  (other-window 1))
```

Comment: thanks. what's `mode` in `(equal mode 'grep-mode)`? It seems neither a variable nor a function to me - I can't find it thru `C-h`. And by the way, how to make it work for `occur`?

Comment: mode is a variable in the compilation-start function which is adviced. These variables are available in the advice. I added an advice for the occur. You may want to consider accepting my answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

After some search, I came up with this solution without advising the built-in functions:

```
(add-hook 'occur-hook (lambda () (pop-to-buffer occur-buf)))
(add-hook 'grep-mode-hook (lambda () (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer "*grep*"))))
(setq help-window-select t)
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook (lambda () (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer "*compilation*"))))
```

It works for `*Occur*`, `*grep*`, `*compilation*` and `*Help*`.

Comment: Untested, but you may wish to try using the `next-error-last-buffer` variable instead of those string literal buffer names.